# Which VB.NET files should I include in a distribution?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I developed a vb.net application, named here as `MyApp`. I would like to distribute the application; only for users. I see that the VS installer exported the following files. I want only the EXE function normally on the target machine.

I made a search though this site and learned that the .vshost and .vshost.exe.manifest are not necessary to export. I guess the same might be true for .PDB and HML, is that right? How about the Microsoft related dlls below? I inted to install the net framework on the target machine. In that case, is it necessary to export the last three DLLs (below) - the Interop and the Hostingprocess DLLs?

```
MyAPP.EXE  
MyAPP.vshost  
MyAPP.vshost.exe.manifest  
MyAPP.PDB  
MyAPP.XML  
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll  
Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to distribute the exe file and all dll files that the application depends on (the references your project has in visual studio). Alternatively you can [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)  the dll:s into the exe in order to only have to distribute the exe.

Comment: So, can I safely remove the .vshost, .vshost.exe.manifest, PDB, and XML from the distribution list and include only all those appear as DLL?  The ILmerg sounds interesting but I wondered if I can use it, because I am working on a .Net 3.5 . Ya it would look like more professional and portable to assemble the dlls into one exe. I will check out that if it handles Frameworks lower than .Net 4.0

Comment: Yes. ilmerge works for 2.0/3.5 as well. Just use the .Net 2.0 option.